# How To Use %time in Python?

Tags: python, time, execution

My Python interpreter is unable to recognize `%time` when executing the line:

```
%time for _ in range(10): my_list = [x * 2 for x in temp_list]
```

I expected to get the execution time of this for loop.

Comment: `%time` is not part of Python. It's a feature of iPython/Jupyter.

Comment: The equivalent outside IPython is the `timeit` module; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have said, `%time` is known as a "magic command" in IPython. Regular Python interpreters cannot run this command, as it is exclusive to only IPython. Running the line you've mentioned will throw a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> temp_list = [1, 3, 2, 4]
>>> %time for _ in range(10): my_list = [x * 2 for x in temp_list]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

On IPython/Jupyter Notebook, the command can be called to get the execution time of a code statement:

```
In [1]: temp_list = [1, 3, 2, 4]

In [2]: %time for _ in range(10): my_list = [x * 2 for x in temp_list]
CPU times: user 10 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 11 µs
Wall time: 12.9 µs
```

---

Documentation for `%time` can be found on IPython's [website](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-time).